# Monitoring new token Creation

Tags: web3.py

Is there anyway to monitor new token creation  using Web3.py?

I tried to accompulish with event_filter.get_all_entries() and using `Topics:` but no luck..

```
    'topics': [None,'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000']
```

`Example Tx`

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9260b52784980ef408581d7c92842bfc39e457022f57bf082da5bdb2785963f1#eventlog
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xdb5db0c3aceb860b97a3978a059153abb9ce6310703b423e6431fec4c4b5b04e#eventlog